# Store Unixtime in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Ok guys I don't know if I'm doing this right, so I'm trying to convert the next string to a timestamp: `23/02/2012`

```
list($d,$m,$y)=explode("/",$_POST[$form_name]);
$date=time(date($d,$m,$y));
```

And it doesn't work, now when I want to display it, what I do`date("d/m/Y",$timestampDB);` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `mktime( 0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y )` to get the timestamp and `date('d/m/y', $timestamp)` to print the date. If you completely control the format of the date string, use `strtotime`

Answer (score 0):

I would start by [reading this](http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/mysql-from-unixtime.php) and that should get you most of the way there.  I would suggest if these are the current timestamps to use mysql's built in feature "Current timestamp on update" rather than try to do it by hand in php.  If you do need to do it by hand also add the time stamp part of hours minutes and seconds so mysql can better compare them natively